# How does openshift multiple pods loadbalancing work?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, load-balancing

In openshift I have a project with one Spring Boot application.
When I send a HTTP request, the Spring Boot application logs a message. I can see this message in the log of the pod in openshift.

When I scale the pod to two and send the same HTTP request, only one of the pods receives this request and logs it. This also happens when I send a 1000 requests using JMeter: only one pod receives all requests.

Doesn't openshift balance the load?

I tried sending multiple requests and expected these requests to be balanced over the 2 pods.

Comment: How are you actually connecting to the container?  Is JMeter running inside the cluster, via a LoadBalancer-type Service, another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pod traffic load balancing, is not an OpenShift-specific mechanism. This is a core kubernetes functionality, handled by [`Service` objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Consider `Service`s as your network path into pods. The `Service` will handle load balancing traffic to multiple pods. `Service`s will balance network traffic *within* the cluster, and when you need to *expose* this network traffic externally you rely on [`Route`s (OpenShift-specific)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/networking/routes/route-configuration.html) or [`Ingress`es (kubernetes-generic)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Without knowing more specifics about how JMeter is accessing the application hosted in the pods, it's difficult to give a solid answer. However, there are several functionalities that `Service`s and `Route`s expose to address pod network load balancing.

There are various [`Route`-specific annotations](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.12/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-route-specific-annotations_route-configuration) that can control network "stickiness". Probably the two most relevant ones are `haproxy.router.openshift.io/balance` and `haproxy.router.openshift.io/disable_cookies`. There are also [`Service` session affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-affinity) options as well.

All of these components work together to get network traffic *into* your application. And only you know the exact path that you're following and able to adjust any necessary configurations as such.

Comment: Thank you Will for your answer. I will dive into the information in the useful links you provided and will get things working.